# typeahead throws an error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code to show typeahead jquery plugin

```
$('#from,#to').typeahead({source: function (query, process) {
    states = [];
    map = {};

    var data = [
        {"stateCode": "CA", "stateName": "California"},
        {"stateCode": "AZ", "stateName": "Arizona"},
        {"stateCode": "NY", "stateName": "New York"},
        {"stateCode": "NV", "stateName": "Nevada"},
        {"stateCode": "OH", "stateName": "Ohio"}
    ];

    $.each(data, function (i, state) {
        map[state.stateName] = state;
        states.push(state.stateName);
    });

    process(states);
}});
```

This is working fine,but when i check the console there was an error throwing,i don't know why

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zw1zu0kL/2/ - how to recreate the issue?

Comment: If i use https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/blob/master/bootstrap3-typeahead.js ,i am getting this error.I think this is only occure,when i use this bootstrap plugin

Comment: with v3.1.0 - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zw1zu0kL/3/

Comment: I just tried with http://tatiyants.com/how-to-use-json-objects-with-twitter-bootstrap-typeahead/ examples

Comment: I updated bootstrap3-typeahead.js v3.0.3 from bootstrap3-typeahead.js v3.0.1,now it is working fine

Comment: @ArunPJohny Do you have any idea about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314552/typeahead-remote-with-defaults-not-working